# If between every two vertices in graph $G$ exists a path of length at most $k$, prove that graph contains a cycle of length at most $2k+1$

Tags: graph-theory

If between every two vertices in graph $G$ exists a path of length at most $k$, prove that graph contains a cycle of length at most $2k+1$. It is known also that $G$ isn't a tree.

So we know that between every two vertices in graph exists a path of length at most $k$, so $G$ is connected, and it isn't a tree, so that means there exists a cycle.

In graph exists a vertex of degree $2$, let's call it $u$. Between $u$ and a vertex $v$ exists path of length $\leq k$. We know that between $v$, and a neighbor of $u$ exists also a path with length $\leq k$.

We started from $u$, went to $v$, and from $v$ went to a neighbor of $u$, and then back to $u$, which means I made a cycle of length $\leq 2k+1$. Is my approach good?

Comment: you need to properly make sure that this is a real cycle, that is there is no $w$ that belongs to both path. Note that if this is the case, there is a cycle whose length is even smaller.

Comment: I agree with @Qise.Your approach is good, but needs clarification. Imagine such a graph $u-u' - v$. You went from $u$ to $v$ and then to $u'$ and to $v$. Where is the cycle here?

Comment: But it is known that graph isn't a tree.

Comment: It isn't mentioned.

Comment: The graph is connected but not a tree, so it contains a cycle. Consider the shortest cycle. Prove by contradiction that its length is at most $2k+1$, i.e., show that if it's longer than that then you can find a shorter cycle.

Comment: Consider the largest cycle, longest path between adjacent vertices is k atmost. Then cycle has length atmost k+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

Let $C$ be the shortest cycle of graph $G$. Choose two vertices on this cycle $u$ and $v$ so that the distance along the cycle between them is largest. Note that then this distance is at most $k$ (otherwise the cycle is not the shortest). From this, deduce that the length of the cycle is at most $2k+1$.

PS. For a triangle this statement is of course true.

Comment: @Gonçalo
 In this problem, cycle length, path length, etc., is understood as length in the sense of abstract graph theory. The length of a cycle is the number of edges in it. Exactly the same for path length. All edges thus have length 1. However, sometimes weighted graphs are considered. But even there the path, edge, cycle length is usually different from the length in the geometrical sense.

Comment: Always happy to help.

Comment: Your proof is terse. The main point is what you have in parentheses, namely, showing that, if there are two points on the cycle whose distance along the cycle exceeds $k$, then a shorter cycle can be constructed. Easy enough to show, but it's the main point of the exercise.

Comment: @bof completely agrees with you. However, sometimes (it seems that in this case too) students lose sight of the method based on choosing the shortest something. But I do not give a proof, but only hints to it, so as not to deprive the student of the pleasure of finding the part of the proof by himself.